# Slide UIWebView over a ImageView (like safari)

Tags: uiwebview, imageview

I think the title says everything about my problem.

The ImageView is not in the UIWebView.

I want that the ImageView is pushed up by the WebView.

Comment: Please don't use the `xcode` tag for questions that are not related to Xcode. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I'm useing XCode. And my question is how to do it in XCode.

Comment: You do it just like you would do it in any other IDE (Eclipse, Visual Studio) or without any IDE at all.

Comment: Dude just back off... quit arguing about his tags and either give him an answer or don't comment at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple.  If you go into your storyboard (or nib) and choose the the webView and choose a color for it's background property, anytime you scroll above the view that background color would appear.  So all you need to do is load an image for that background color.

In your viewDidLoad method, place this bit of code:

```
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

and where it says `background.png`
just put the image name that you loaded into your project.

Hope this helps!